# define a Route to show images via timthumb php script in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to have a Route that takes image Dimension and source and return Cropped and resized image via [**timthumb**](https://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/) php script.

I put *timthumb.php* file in a folder in *public* directory and I wrote this Route:

```
Route::get('/showImage/{w}/{h}/{src}', function ($w , $h , $src) {

    $img    =   'public/plugins/timthumb/timthumb.php?src='.$src.'&w='.$w.'&h='.$h;
    return Response::make($img, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg'));
})->where('src', '[A-Za-z0-9\/\.\-\_]+');
```

But nothing happen.

How can I access to timthumb.php file and send it required parameters and get result image?

**Update:**
this is structure of Public directory and placement of timthumb and images folder :

[image]

According to , I try :

```
$img    =   'public/plugins/timthumb/timthumb.php?src=../../'.$src.'&w='.$w.'&h='.$h;
```

And :

```
$img    =   'public/plugins/timthumb/timthumb.php?src=public/'.$src.'&w='.$w.'&h='.$h;
```

But none of them does not work for bellow URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/showImage/100/200/upload/slideshow/slide2.jpg
```

Comment: What does nothing happens mean exactly?

Comment: means that when i try this for a simple image, just a broken image icon shown in chrome. i try _http://localhost:8000/showImage/100/200/upload/slideshow/slide2.jpg_ while all Parameters is given and _upload/slideshow/slide2.jpg_ exists But it is not shown.

Comment: I think the problem is, that your path is relative to the script you are using. So it's looking for your image at public/plugins/timthumb/upload...

Comment: @Tim, I updated my Question by new Informations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [`league/glide`](http://glide.thephpleague.com/). Watch [Using Glide in Laravel](https://vimeo.com/118089742) to get started.

Comment: does it support for cache like timthumb?

Comment: Im not sure of that. Timthumb developer does not provide support for it ( https://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/timthumb-technical-support/ ). Im sure you can do all the image processing you require with  league/glide.

Comment: @ahmad Author of Glide here. Yes, it does support caching, this is pretty core to how Glide works. See the docs [here](http://glide.thephpleague.com/1.0/config/source-and-cache/) for more info.

Comment: @Jonathan,Yes I am using Glide too.It is great.

Answer (score 2):

The better way to use timthumb image in Laravel using [intervention/image](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)
Install this package.

Update your Route:

```
Route::get('showImage/{w}/{h}/{src}', function ($w , $h , $src) 
{

    $img_path = public_path().'/'.$src;
    $img = Image::make($img_path)->resize($w, $h);

    return $img->response('jpg');
})->where('src', '[A-Za-z0-9\/\.\-\_]+');
```

**OR Image Cache**

Install [intervention/imagecache](http://image.intervention.io/use/cache) package

```
Route::get('showImage/{w}/{h}/{src}', function ($w , $h , $src) 
    {

        $img_path = public_path().'/'.$src;
        $img =  Image::cache(function($image)use($w,$h,$img_path) {
                return $image->make($img_path)->resize($w, $h);
            });
        return Response::make($img, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg']);
    })->where('src', '[A-Za-z0-9\/\.\-\_]+');
```

Image URL would be as below:

**http://<< Domain Name >>/showImage/800/400/Desert.jpg**

Comment: i tried intervention already, but it has many Cache issues and does not support cache very well while that is very important for me.

Comment: Use  intervention/imagecache package for Cache issues.